# Как функцию переместить в класс, ошибка The above error occurred in the <Lesson> component

Tags: reactjs

Пишет ошибку `"The above error occurred in the <Lesson> component:`
Когда я хочу функция которая повторяется при проверке времени и комнаты
Не пойму как написать код чтобы его не дублировать всегда.

Вот весь код реализации https://codepen.io/rusline/pen/NyBYVY?editors=0011

```js
function Lesson(props) {
    data.map((lesson, i) => {
        let date = new Date(lesson.startTime);
        let time = `${date.getHours()}:${(date.getMinutes()<10?'0':'')+date.getMinutes()}`;
        if(lesson.room === props.room && time === props.time) {
            return (
                <td key={i}>
                    <div className='lesson'>
                        <p>{lesson.title}</p>
                        <p>{lesson.teacher}</p>
                        {lesson.participaints.map(participaints => {
                            return <p key={participaints.toString()}>{participaints}</p>
                        })}
                    </div>
                </td>
            )
        }
    })
}

class Calendar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            ....
            <tr>
                <th scope='row'>10:00</th>
                <Lesson room='Комната 1' time='9:30'/>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
    const data = [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "room": "Комната 1",
            "title": "Тренинг по личностному росту",
            "teacher": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
            "participaints": ["Иванов Иван", "Петров Петр", "Семенов Семен"],
            "startTime": "2017-02-24 9:00:00",
            "endTime": "2017-02-24 10:00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "room": "Комната 2",
            "title": "Семинар по управление персоналом",
            "teacher": "Иванова Марина Ивановна",
            "participaints": ["Иванова Марина", "Шамсутдинов Евгений"],
            "startTime": "2017-02-24 9:30:00",
            "endTime": "2017-02-24 10:00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "room": "Комната 1",
            "title": "Тренинг по обучение персонала",
            "participaints": ["Смирнов Владимир"],
            "teacher": "Петров Петр Петрович",
            "startTime": "2017-02-24 10:00:00",
            "endTime": "2017-02-24 10:15:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А текст ошибки то собственно где? Пока судя по всему жалуется на то, что стейтлесс компонент не возвращает ничего.

Comment: "The above error occurred in the <Lesson> component:
    in Lesson (created by Calendar)
    in tr (created by Calendar)
    in tbody (created by Calendar)
    in table (created by Calendar)
    in div (created by Calendar)
    in Calendar

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://fb.me/react-error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries."

Comment: если сейчас зайдешь в codepen то увидишь ее

Comment: В браузере Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See https://fb.me/react-crossorigin-error for more information.
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:626)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:476)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:10908)
    at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:11556)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:11509)
    at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:11420)

Comment: at scheduleWorkImpl (react-dom.development.js:11274)
    at scheduleWork (react-dom.development.js:11231)
    at scheduleTopLevelUpdate (react-dom.development.js:11735)
    at Object.updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:11773)

Comment: В общем то да, судя по всему есть 2 проблемы: 1) Lesson не возвращает ничего; 2) пытается что-то загрузить без должных прав. Первое лечится оборачиванием всего что формируется в Lesson в какой-то блок и возврата либо этого, либо null. Второе уже надо по факту смотреть что и откуда вы пытаетесь подключить, что выдает ошибку CORS.

Comment: И да, ошибки оформите в тело вопроса.

Comment: "2) пытается что-то загрузить без должных прав. Первое лечится оборачиванием всего что формируется в Lesson в какой-то блок и возврата либо этого, либо null"  Это подразумевается что обернуть в div или try/catch?

Answer (score 0):

Надо вернуть что data саму

```js
function Lesson(props) {
    return data.map((lesson, i) => {
        let date = new Date(lesson.startTime);
        let time = `${date.getHours()}:${(date.getMinutes()<10?'0':'')+date.getMinutes()}`;
        if(lesson.room === props.room && time === props.time) {
            return (
                <td key={i}>
                    <div className='lesson'>
                        <p>{lesson.title}</p>
                        <p>{lesson.teacher}</p>
                        {lesson.participaints.map(participaints => {
                            return <p key={participaints.toString()}>{participaints}</p>
                        })}
                    </div>
                </td>
            )
        }
    })
}
```